# Vue.js $emit not being received by parent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am having difficuly working out why the following code code is not working for a child and parent single page components.

Child.vue

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'ChildComponent',
  data () {
      return {}
  }
  mounted: function() {
      this.emitSignal()
  },
  methods: {
    emitSignal: function () {
      console.log('>>emitSignal()')
      this.$emit('my_signal')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Parent.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
        <child-component v-on:my_signal="doSomething"></child-component>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent.vue'
export default {
    name: 'ParentComponent',
    data () {
      return {
      }
    },
    components: {
      ChildComponent
    },
    methods: {
      doSomething: function () {
        console.log('doSomething')
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

If I run the application, I see the child emits the signal >>emitSignal() in console, but the parent function 'doSomething' does not run.

Any idea what I could be missing?

NB I also tried an event bus as per here: https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/, the child fires but again the parent does not intercep the signal and run the specified function.

Comment: Use this.$parent.$emit('my_signal') instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `emit` code is fine, besides a comma missing after `data` block in Child.vue

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/63t082p2/42/

```
<div id="app">
  <child v-on:my_signal="doSomething"></child>
</div>

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    methods: {
    doSomething: function () {
      console.log('doSomething')
    }
  },
  components: {
    'child' : {
      mounted: function() {
          this.emitSignal()
      },
      methods: {
        emitSignal: function () {
          console.log('>>emitSignal()')
          this.$emit('my_signal')
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks I forked your fiddle as (although it did run the relevant console.log lines) there were various errors in the console which I found a little confusing at first https://jsfiddle.net/9qz1Lds3/

Comment: @MemeDeveloper thank you, looks like something has changed in Vue during these 2 years :)

Comment: Yup of course - am sure lots has changed, added in case anyone else find this answer and like me finds it useful. thanks. +1